# The file is corrupt and cannot be opened, C#, XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

Tried to create XML report using XmlWriter.
Strangely, for large number of records I get the following error when try to open the report file with MS Excel: "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened". However, the report file is not corrupt I think, as with other editors (e.g notepad) I am able to open the file and make sure that the content is OK.

In the code below, the Loop works OK for 1995 upper limit, however it fails when the upper limit is 1996.

Thanks in advance,

========================================================================

```
    private static void WriteReport(XmlWriter writer, ReportingFilters filters, DataContext context)
    {

        writer.WriteStartElement("Table"); // Begin Table

        writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "ExpandedColumnCount", null, "7");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "ExpandedRowCount", null, "2000");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("x", "FullColumns", null, "1");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("x", "FullRows", null, "1");

        writer.WriteStartElement("Column");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Width", null, "200");
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteStartElement("Column");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Width", null, "125");
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteStartElement("Column");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Width", null, "100");
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteStartElement("Column");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Width", null, "75");
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteStartElement("Column");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Width", null, "75");
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        // Write the title.
        writer.WriteStartElement("Row");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Cell");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "StyleID", null, "BorderedTitle");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Data");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Type", null, "String");
        writer.WriteString("Selected Dates: " + filters.StartDate.ToShortDateString() + " -" + filters.EndDate.ToShortDateString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        // Write the title.
        writer.WriteStartElement("Row");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Cell");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "StyleID", null, "BorderedTitle");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Data");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Type", null, "String");
        writer.WriteString("Date Report was Run: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        //.. etc

        var reportResults = ReportingManager.GetHospitalHitRate(context, filters);
        var totalDemos = 0;
        var totalMatched = 0;

            // Loop works OK for 1995, 1996 fails with "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened"
            for (int m = 0; m < 1995; m++ )
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Row"); // Begin Content Row

                writer.WriteStartElement("Cell");
                writer.WriteStartElement("Data");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Type", null, "String");
                writer.WriteString("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("Cell");
                writer.WriteStartElement("Data");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Type", null, "String");
                writer.WriteString("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("Cell");
                writer.WriteStartElement("Data");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Type", null, "String");
                writer.WriteString("cccccccccccc");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("Cell");
                writer.WriteStartElement("Data");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Type", null, "String");
                writer.WriteString("dddddddddd");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("Cell");
                writer.WriteStartElement("Data");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Type", null, "String");

                //.. etc
                writer.WriteString("%");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteEndElement();

            }

        //.. etc

        writer.WriteEndElement(); // End Table.
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do yuo get the error? What's the stack trace?

Comment: OK, maybe you don't want to use Linq2Xml for some reason, but why don't you write a utility method like `WriteNode` and make your code more readable.

Comment: What does the code look like that opens/creates the XmlWriter ? i.e. what does the caller do with the XmlWriter ?

Comment: When Excel says that the file is corrupt, it probably refers to the Xml document rather than the low-level file in the file system (which is all right as a file and thus can be opened in text editors). As you are using an XmlWriter, Excel may not even mean the well-formedness of the Xml document, but rather something like unexpected or missing elements or attributes with respect to the expected schema.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I get the error when I right click on the report file and say open with Excel. With other editors I do not get any error. Linq2Xml is a GOOD idea, I'll make a try. I am inline with your ideas, but the question is what makes the file incorrect... as you see in the attached code the Loop works OK when upper limit is hard coded to 1995, however when this hard coded value becomes 1996 MS Excel fails to open it with "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened" message. So, if the formatting is incorrect, then Excel should not be able to open the file with smaller loops.

Comment: Again, thank you for your comments.
I have tried with Linq2Xml and no similar issue is noticed.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I have found "XML Spreadsheet Reference" at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Turned out that I had been using attribute ss:ExpandedRowCount, and I set it to 2000.
And in those cases when the number of records were more than this number, XML Spreadsheet document was considered as invalid.
Once I removed this optional attribute, the genereted report worked fine.

Attribute:  ss:ExpandedRowCount
Description: Specifies the total number of rows in this table without regard for sparseness. This attribute defines the overall size of the table, if the specified rows and columns were expanded to full size. If specified, this attribute must be in sync with the table. Row indices in the table should begin at 1 and go to ExpandedRowCount. If this value is out-of-sync with the table, the specified XML Spreadsheet document is invalid.